# Code is not entering if statement while all statements are valid. (Test)

Tags: java

```
public void powerUpCollision(PowerUp object, Rectangle2D playerR) {
    Ellipse2D powerUpR = object.getShape();
    if (powerUpR.intersects(playerR) && !object.isHit()) {
        if (this.player.getPowerUp() == null) {
            if (object instanceof PUInvincible) {
                this.player.setPowerUp((PUInvincible) object);
            } else if (object instanceof PUSlowMotion) {
                this.player.setPowerUp((PUSlowMotion) object);
            } else if (object instanceof PUSpeedBoost) {
                this.player.setPowerUp((PUSpeedBoost) object);
            }
        }
        object.setHit(true);
        new SecurePlatformRunner(() -> collidedObjects.add(object));
    }
}
 public void checkCollisions(Player player, List<GameObject> gameObjects) {
    collidedObjects = new ArrayList<>();

    Rectangle2D.Double playerR = player.getShape();
    for (GameObject object : gameObjects) {
        if (object instanceof Coin) {
            coinCollision((Coin) object, playerR);
        } else if (object instanceof Obstacle || object instanceof Rocket) {
            obstacleCollision(object, playerR);
        } else if (object instanceof PowerUp) {
            powerUpCollision((PowerUp) object, playerR);
        }
    }
}



 @ParameterizedTest
@CsvSource({"PUInvincible", "PUSpeedBoost", "PUSlowMotion"})
public void test_checkCollision_powerUp(String powerUpName) {
    PowerUp powerUp;
    Sprite sprite = Mockito.mock(Sprite.class);
    Mockito.when(sprite.getHeight()).thenReturn(10.0);
    Mockito.when(sprite.getWidth()).thenReturn(10.0);

    Player player = Mockito.mock(Player.class);
    Mockito.when(player.getShape()).thenReturn(new Rectangle2D.Double(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 5.0));

    gameController = Mockito.mock(GameController.class);
    Launcher.setGameController(gameController);

    switch(powerUpName) {
        case "PUInvincible":
            powerUp = new PUInvincible(5.0, 5.0, sprite);
            break;
        case "PUSpeedBoost":
            powerUp = new PUSpeedBoost(5.0,5.0, sprite);
            break;
        case "PUSlowMotion":
            powerUp = new PUSlowMotion(5.0,5.0, sprite);
            break;
        default:
            powerUp = null;
    }

    List<GameObject> gameObjects = new ArrayList<>();
    gameObjects.add(powerUp);
    gameObjects.add(player);

    gameScene.checkCollisions(player, gameObjects );
    assertThat(player.getPowerUp()).isEqualTo(powerUp);
    assertThat(powerUp.isHit()).isTrue();
}
```

I'm trying to test the checkCollision method and in turn want to test powerUpCollision. The way I'm testing it right now does not work though. For some reason my test is not entering the if and else-if statements where I check which kind of powerUp should be set. I don't understand why this is as all the conditions are true upon entering the statements.

Comment: using instanceof is a bad practice and usually shows design issues.

Comment: If it is not entering an if  block then obiously the condition is not true at all.

Comment: Debug your code

Comment: In your test, you're passing player and a gameObjects list that also contains player again.  Maybe remove player from the gameObjects?

Comment: `if (powerUpR.intersects(playerR) && !object.isHit())` looks like you check if the player runs over a powerup and simultaneously that object should not be hit. Can't think about that case ever happen (intersecting should indicate the object being hit). But that is just a guess…